# How to get multiple rows cells in one label C# windows form

Tags: c#, datagridview, label

I need to select multiple rows in my dataGridView and for all selected rows I need to set all ProductsNames [cell 2] to one label.
Here's my code

```
Bill bill = new Bill();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView2.SelectedCells)
{         
    bill.label12.Text = this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +  this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    bill.label14.Text = this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    bill.label15.Text = this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    bill.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    bill.Show();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  If so please post it.

Comment: no im not getting error i get 2x the same last row ProductName

Comment: what i need is for example three selected rows Products Names in the label

Comment: Why are you looping through the “selected cells” then set the labels from the “current row”? Looping through the “selected cells” appears unnecessary since the labels will be updated with the SAME values from the “current row” as the “current row” will NOT change in the loop. “SelectedCells” and “CurrentRow” are two different things. Did you mean to set the labels to the “selected cells”?

Comment: @JohnG yes i want to set label to selected cells

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what exactly your requirements are, however from what little is revealed, I am guessing that you want the user to be able to select “multiple rows”, then, through some unknown mechanism these “selected rows” populate several labels. This is about as much as I can decipher here.

Since it appears you are looking for rows, with full row select mode set, I am guessing it may be easier to loop through the `SelectedRows` as opposed to `SelectedCells`.

The thing to keep in mind for all of the “Selected” cells/rows/columns methods is that the collections are stored from a NEWEST to OLDEST order. In other words, the `SelectedRows` collection is a stack,  each time the user adds to the selection, the newly selected cells will go to the top of the `SelectedRows` collection and everything else moves down. This enables you to track the order the user selected the cells if necessary.

Given this, from your question it appears you need at least two rows. Since multi-select is true, you must assume that the user may have more than two rows selected or possibly only one row selected. This can be checked by looking at the number of `SelectedRows.Count`. It is not clear what you would do here if there is more than two rows selected. I assume possibly use the first two selected rows, or the last two selected rows.

Below is an example that demonstrates the `SelectedRows` collection. The `DataGridViews` `SelectionMode` should be set to `FullRowSelect`. A button is used to loop through all the selected rows and outputs some of the values into a text box. I Hope this makes sense.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SetColumns();
  FillGrid();
}

private void SetColumns() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col" + i, "Col" + i);
  }
}

private void FillGrid() {
  int newRowIndex = 0;
  for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    newRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; col++) {
      dataGridView1.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[col].Value = "R" + row + "C" + col;
    }
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow curRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
    textBox1.Text += "--- New row ---" + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text += "Label1: " + curRow.Cells["Col2"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text += "Label2: " + curRow.Cells["Col8"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text += "Label3: " + curRow.Cells["Col6"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
  }
}
```